# android textview seen as linearlayout

Tags: android, textview, simpleadapter

I'm trying to fill a simple adapter with textviews, but he seem to see one of them(and only one) as a linearlayout, sending me the errore `android.linearlayout is not a view that can be bound by this simpleadapter`.
here is java

```
final SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.mainafficheitem,       
    new String[] {"description","quantite", "numero", "prix"}, 
new int[] {R.id.mainlistdescription,R.id.mainlistquantite, R.id.mainlistnumero, R.id.mainlistprix});
```

Now this work if I take out the `quantite` and the `R.id.mainlistquantite` out, but crash with the error when used.
In my xml file, `R.id.mainlistquantite` is indeed a textview :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainlistquantite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/consultaffichelayoutdroit"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
     />
```

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: the `TextView`is inside a linear layout. put the text view as the root of that view.

Comment: it's actually inside a relative layout,who is the root of the view,but all other 3 are inside that relative-layout too,without any problems (some are event inside a linearlayout)